# How to change the height of <ul> element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html elements anchors generated in `<ul>` element.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav pull-left">
  <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;background-color:red;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sites.list" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="sites"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i></a></li>
  <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;background-color:#0094ff;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="events"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i></a></li>
 
</ul>
```

My question is how can I make smaller `<li>` element height while to preserve the height of the icon (i.e can I make the height of the `<li>` element as height of the glyph icon inside)?

Comment: I think you may need to re-word your question.  You can make a UL any height you desire using the CSS height property, however this may not have any affect visually. My guess here is your really asking can the LI height be changed without affecting the glyph icon inside...is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Change the height of `.navbar-brand` to `auto` instead of `50px`:

```
<li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;background-color:red">
    <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sites.list" style="padding: 9px; height: auto;" title="sites">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/xosixuzeyi/1/edit?html,output)

And it would be nice if you could remove your inline CSS and create those styles in a separate external file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of `a` element.

If you change the height of `li` element, the element would increase in size but the whole of it won't be clickable. So you better target the `a` tag and change its height.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav pull-left">
 <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;background-color:red;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sites.list" style="padding: 11px 09px; height:80px" title="sites"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i></a></li>
                <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;background-color:#0094ff;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="events"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i></a></li>
 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override the class `.navbar-brand` when you are going to use CSS. For now, since you are using inline style, set the height to auto.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav pull-left">
 <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;background-color:red;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sites.list" style="padding: 11px 09px; height:auto" title="sites"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i></a></li>
                <li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;background-color:#0094ff;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList" style="padding: 11px 09px; height:auto" title="events"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i></a></li>
 
</ul>
```

Comment: @Michael You are trying to reduce the height of the *li* not the *ul* im guessing. In that case above solution should work.